# incorrect status bar translucent displays on sony on lollipop

Tags: android, styles, statusbar

I have my styles.xml in values-v21.
When I run my app on different Sony devices I see statusbar translucent like in android 4.4, but not 5.x. Anyone know the solution?
code:

```
<style name="BATheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> 

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> 

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> 
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item> 
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> 
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item> 

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item> 

    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AnimActivity</item> 

</style> 

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle"> 
    <item name="spinBars">true</item> 
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item> 
</style> 

<style name="AnimActivity" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity"> 
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/act_in</item> 
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/act_out</item> 
    <!--  <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/act_out</item>--> 
    <!-- <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/act_out</item> --> 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

from the "BATheme", or change it in:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```

if there a styles.xml with that parameter set as true.